# Excel Macro, Copy Cell to a location if a cell has a value

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am looking for some help with excel Macros eg. If a value is found in Desc that matches Bill/car/rent/tax the Cost value copied to the correct column.

```
Cost    Desc        Bill    Car Rent    Tax

155     Bill                    
165     Rent                    
195     tax
```

```
Cost    Desc        Bill  Car   Rent    Tax

155     Bill        155         
165     Rent              165       
195     tax                     195
```

Can this be done? 
Thanks in advance. I have attempted and can select the value but not sure how to paste it etc, not very good with vba macros.

Thanks for the replies. sorry I am still confused just learning stuff atm. this is what I got maybe its not the correct way to go about doing it.

```html
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
    If Cell.Value = "Bill" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy

       
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your attempted code. Click on edit and add the code at the bottom of your question. Do not post it as comment.

Comment: I have added my attempted code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are fixed, you could loop through the "Desc" column and then copy set the values of the other columns to the value of column "Cost".

```
Sub SortMyColumns()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim costColumn As Integer
    Dim descColumn As Integer
    Dim billColumn As Integer
    Dim carColumn As Integer
    Dim rentColumn As Integer
    Dim taxColumn As Integer

    'Change values according to columns
    costColumn = 1
    descColumn = 2
    billColumn = 3
    carColumn = 4
    rentColumn = 5
    taxColumn = 6

    lastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, descColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through the "Desc" column and check values
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, descColumn).Value = "Bill" Then
            Worksheets(1).Cells(i, billColumn).Value = _
                Worksheets(1).Cells(i, costColumn).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This only works if your columns always stay the same.

VLOOKUP shouldn't work because the columns are in the wrong order. Cost should come after Desc for VLOOKUP to work. VLOOKUP cannot look to the left.

Comment: First Thanks for helping, I keep getting an error:                                    Run-time error '1004': 
Application-defined or object-defined error - I removed "ElseIf ..." and added "End Sub" at the end.

Comment: The 1 in Worksheets(1) has to be replaced with your worksheets number or a string of your worksheets name. I think that may be the problem.

Comment: I have mine set as the default value sheet1. I am not getting the error now. but its not doing anything :) How do i paste the selection. sorry thanks for you help

Comment: No need to paste anything.

Comment: ok. Its not copying the cost value to the Bill column. anything I need to do?

Comment: The Offset is calculated wrong. I have to figure out why. Use the changed code above. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a sub to find the value (vlookup/match) but not sure how to get that value into the worksheet?

to check or do something if a cell has a value
you can do it by checking if a cell is empty, if true do this, if false do that.

```
With worksheets("name")
if .range("A1") = empty then
do something (for example, Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup() )
else
do something else ("exit sub" if you want it to do nothing)
end with
```

To store a value and to place it somewhere into an active sheet

```
dim i (this doesn't have to be "i") as string

i = your function
worksheets("name").range("A2").value = i
```